# Is there a way to make each icon in this render a hologram?

Tags: texturing, compositing-nodes

I made this texture out of an image of icons with transparency, and I was wondering if there is a way to have all the icons on the outer sphere point to the inner sphere with little hologram stems?  I'm assuming compositor nodes but I can't figure out how to get them to diverge to the inner sphere.

**EDIT:** this is not a duplicate of [How to create a hologram projection with light rays?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57498/how-to-create-a-hologram-projection-with-light-rays) My question relates to making the stem of the hologram without a mesh (i.e. cone), but rather compositor based.

This is the render:

[image]

This is the node setup:

[image]

Basically trying to get non-mesh based way of achieving this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a hologram projection with light rays?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57498/how-to-create-a-hologram-projection-with-light-rays)

Comment: Yep I've used that article before.  The problem is they are mesh based.  You need a cone for the stem of the hologram.  I'm wondering if there is a pure compositor-based way to connect the icon material since they are not separate icons but just a sphere with transparency.